# Selecting based on GUID oracle server

Tags: oracle, guid

I'm having some issues selecting data from my tables based on their GUID after reading the values into variables in visual basic.

In my database the GUID is stored as a byte array.

I read the GUID from my database using

```
dim g as guid 
g = New Guid(CType(recData(0).Item(0), Byte()))
```

The issue I'm having it re-formatting it to select a row based on it.

Essentially, I'm not quite sure how to do the reverse of what I have done here. I've decoded the data to be used in visual basic, but now I'm not sure how to re-encode it to select based on the guid in my oracle database.

I have tried using `g.toByteArray()` but it does not appear to be correct.

Comment: Are you seeing the problem of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289734/convert-from-oracles-raw16-to-nets-guid

Comment: No matter really though since if you pulled 77DB966B620D4FEBB9959D016E0BD590 as the GUID from Oracle you can just use that in the Select statement since Oracle will cast it to a string. For example, `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyPK = '77DB966B620D4FEBB9959D016E0BD590';` where MyPK is defined as RAW(16) in the table def.

Comment: I was overthinking the problem, this worked fine @topshot