# Why does this ADO.NET query return no results?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracle12c, datareader

I have the following code that executes a SQL statement and looks for a result.

```
var sql = @"select BOQ_IMPORT_ID "
          + "from ITIS_PRJ.PRJ_BOQ_IMPORT_HEADER "
          + "where PROJECT_ID = :Projectid "
          + "order by CREATED_ON desc "
          + "fetch first 1 row only";
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(LocalCreateParameterRaw("ProjectId", projectId));
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
        reader.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, 16);
        var boqId = new Guid(buffer);
        return boqId;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Where `LocalCreateParameterRaw` is declared as:

```
public static OracleParameter LocalCreateParameterRaw(string name, object value)
{
    OracleParameter oracleParameter = new OracleParameter();
    oracleParameter.ParameterName = name;
    oracleParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Raw;
    oracleParameter.Size = 16;
    oracleParameter.Value = value;
    return oracleParameter;
}
```

The underlying type for 'projectId' is 'Guid'.

The `if (reader.Read())` always evaluates to `false`, despite there being exactly one row in the table. It normally should return only one row.

Using [GI Oracle Profiler](http://www.iacosoft.com/home/tools.asp) I can catch the SQL sent to the db, but only once did the profiler provide a value for the `:ProjectId` parameter, and it was in lower case. Like that it returned no results, but as soon as I applied `UPPER` to that value, I get a result.

It looks like I somehow have to get my parameter into uppercase for the query to work, but I have no idea how. Yet if I do a `ToString().ToUpper()` on the `projectId` GUID, I get a parameter binding error.

**VERY IMPORTANT:**
I have tried removing the `where` clause altogether, and no longer add a parameter, so all rows in the table should be returned, yet still no results.

Comment: If your query returns always just one row and one column then you may consider `cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Nope. `ExecuteScalar` returns `null`.

Comment: @ProfK - See if this is directly related, it has to do with how Guid's are translated between .net and oracle. [Convert from Oracle's RAW(16) to .NET's GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7289734/1260204)

Comment: If you are still having trouble it would help if you included the underlying type and the value for the variable `projectId` (variable being used as the parameter in your query).

Comment: @Igor I have added that, and the type is 'Guid'.

Comment: @ProfK - updated my answer below. Pass a byte array to as value instead of the .net guid instance. You can convert using `ToByteArray` method on Guid.

Comment: @Igor I have tried that, `parm.Value = projectId.ToByteArray();` with the same zero result.

Comment: Have you tried the code posted in [Convert from Oracle's RAW(16) to .NET's GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7289734/1260204)? Basically `parm.Value = BitConverter.ToString(projectId.ToByteArray()).Replace("-", "");`

Comment: @ProfK I think I figured out the binding error when you tried `projectId.ToString().ToUpper()`. check updated answer.

Comment: I have removed the `where` clause and any parameters, and still get no data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how, but making the SQL string a verbatim string (prefixed with `@`) causes the proc to work. So, it doesn't work with:

```
var sql = @"SELECT BOQ_IMPORT_ID "
      + "FROM ITIS_PRJ.PRJ_BOQ_IMPORT_HEADER "
      + "WHERE PROJECT_ID = :projectid "
      + "ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC "
      + "FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY";
```

Yet the same command string in SQL Developer executes and returns results. When I make my SQL string verbatim, as below, I get results.

```
var sql = @"select BOQ_IMPORT_ID 
            from ITIS_PRJ.PRJ_BOQ_IMPORT_HEADER 
            where PROJECT_ID = :ProjectId 
            order by CREATED_ON desc 
            fetch first 1 row only";
```

Comment: Wow. Ok. What happens if you remove the `@` from the first example.

Comment: I totally missed that prefixed to the first string.

Comment: @Nkosi Wow, it also works if I just remove the `@` from the first example.

Comment: @ProfK Any chance that the source code contains invisilbe characters(unbreakable space, null-symbol, ...)? You could perform a test: `var sql = @"SELECT BOQ_IMPORT_ID FROM ITIS_PRJ.PRJ_BOQ_IMPORT_HEADER"
      + "WHERE PROJECT_ID = :projectid "` If it returns all rows it means that verbatim is null-character ended(The null character '\0' is used to terminate C strings)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I suspect this is the case, as changing between a verbatim and a concatenated string changes the outcome.

Comment: @ProfK Did you tried the concatenated verbatim + normal string? I am really curious if it's really the case of `NULL-terminator` like: `var sql  = @"SELECT 1 AS BOQ_IMPORT_ID FROM dual " + "WHERE 1=2"`.

Comment: If you have notepad++, you will be able to inspect any such issues by right clicking on the bottom right corner and selecting the platform on which the file was created.

Answer (score 2):

Using a more general approach, try the following

```
var sql = "SELECT BOQ_IMPORT_ID "
      + "FROM ITIS_PRJ.PRJ_BOQ_IMPORT_HEADER "
      + "WHERE PROJECT_ID = :projectid "
      + "ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC "
      + "FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY";
using (DbConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionString))
using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    DbParameter parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "projectid";
    parameter.Value = projectId.ToString("N").ToUpper(); //<-- NOTE FORMAT USED

    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;

    conn.Open();

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read()) {
        var boqId = new Guid((byte[])reader[0]);
        return boqId;
    }
    return null;
}
```

> It looks like I somehow have to get my parameter into uppercase for the query to work, but I have no idea how. Yet if I do a `ToString().ToUpper()` on the `projectId` GUID, I get a parameter binding error.

Reference [Guid.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)

> Specifier `N` formats it to 32 digits: 00000000000000000000000000000000

When no format is provided the default format is `D` which would include 32 digits separated by hyphens.

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

That would explain your binding error.